# What is the lowest channel no. supported in agora web?

Tags: agora.io

We are looking at the [agora web tutorial 1-to-1 repository on github](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1). The channel no. specified is 1000. We would like to know the lowest channel no. supported.

```
Channel: <input id="channel" type="text" value="1000" size="4"></input>
```

The [documentation v1.12](https://docs.agora.io/en/1.12/user_guide/communication/overview.html#scale) mentions number of channels supported is unlimited.

We appreciate the cooperation of forum members.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on this. As far as I know, the channel name will be interpreted as a string.